# Dynamically add iron-list and all it's data

Tags: polymer, dart

I've faced a problem that I can't solve. I need to add `<iron-list>` element from code, assign its items and so on.

I've googled it for several days now, but in all examples I find `<iron-list>` is already added in HTML.

I've tried this:

```
var msgs = new List();//I've added some data to this list 
var listTab = new Element.div();
var list = new Element.tag("iron-list");
var template = new Element.tag("template");
var item = new Element.tag("paper-item");
item.innerHtml = "[[item.text]]";
template.children.add(item);
list.children.add(template);
list.items = msgs;
list.as = "item";
listTab.children.add(list);
```

And this causes the following error:

```
iron-list requires a template to be provided in light-dom
Uncaught Unhandled exception:
TypeError: this.ctor is not a function
```

The following code causes the same error:

```
var msgs = new List();//I've added some data to this list 
var listTab = new Element.div();
IronList list = new IronList();
var template = new Element.tag("template");
var item = new Element.tag("paper-item");
item.innerHtml = "[[item.text]]";
template.children.add(item);
list.children.add(template);
list.items = msgs;
list.as = "item";
listTab.children.add(list);
```

And finally I've tried a very straight-forward solution, which didn't work either:

```
var list= new Element.html('<iron-list items="{{msgs}}" as="item"><template><paper-item>[[item.text]]</paper-item></template></iron-list>');
listTab.children.add(list);
```

The error:

```
Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON
Removing disallowed element <IRON-LIST> from [object DocumentFragment]
Removing disallowed element <PAPER-ITEM> from [object DocumentFragment]
Removing disallowed element <ARRAY-SELECTOR> from iron-list
Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Bad state: No element
```

I would really be grateful for the working solution of adding `<iron-list>` element from dart code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
  ..allowElement('iron-list', attributes: ['items', 'as'])
  ..allowElement(...);

var list= new Element.html('<iron-list items="{{msgs}}" as="item"><template><paper-item>[[item.text]]</paper-item></template></iron-list>',
    validator: validator);
listTab.children.add(list);
```

or

```
var list= new Element.html('<iron-list items="{{msgs}}" as="item"><template><paper-item>[[item.text]]</paper-item></template></iron-list>',
    treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted);
listTab.children.add(list);
```

Comment: Thanks, both solutions work! 

But I still get error: `Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON`

Comment: `Polymer::Attributes: couldnt decode Array as JSON`

Comment: `item.innerHtml = "[[item.text]]";` won't create a binding. Try just `item.innerHtml = item.text;` Your error message probably comes from something else though.

Comment: I think there is some problem with the List I'm adding as data for iron-list. At least, none of them appear. I'll try to find the problem :)

Comment: Polymer bindings like `items="{{msgs}}"` also won't work for HTML added this way. You can try querying the list after you added it to the document and the assign `myList.items=msgs;`. My Polymer knowledge is quite rusty :-/

Comment: You are right. I've assigned Iron list items in other function on rendering the list, and it works. I'm so grateful for your help! Thanks a lot!